# Making A square with asterisk in C

Tags: c

I am new to C language ,please help me .
Well i am writing a code to make a square of asterisks. but i can't figure how to make the square completely. Here's my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int n;

    for(n=1;n<5;n++){
        printf("*");
    }
    for (n=1;n<4;n++){
        printf("*\n");
    }
    for (n=1;n<=5;n++){
        printf("*");
    }
    for(n=5;n<=1;n--){
        printf("*\n");
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks !!
    it Should Exacxtly be Like

```
                           *****
                           *   *
                           *   *
                           *   *
                           *****
```

Comment: A square of sterik? You mean asterisk, yes? Also, _please_ format your code.

Comment: @jrd1 - Wow!  You're a lot better than I am -- I had no idea who Sterik was or why he needed a square.

Comment: @HotLicks: Nah. It was just a lucky guess. ;)

Comment: You cannot make square without in advance knowing your display character's aspect ratio. You will just get series of rectangles most of the time... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you wish to create a *hollow square of asterisks*:

Think about *how* you'd create it. After some thought, you'll realize that:

1. The first and last rows are all asterisks.
2. For all other rows, the first and last columns of those rows are all asterisks.
3. Everything else is a space.

Using that, we can construct:

```
const int n = 5;

for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j < n; j++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == n - 1) {
            printf("*");
        }
        else if(j == 0 || j == n - 1) {
            printf("*");
        }
        else {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Which can be put into a general solution for a `n*m` case:

```
const int ROWS = 5;
const int COLS = 5;

for(int i=0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j < COLS; j++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == ROWS - 1) {
            printf("*");
        }
        else if(j == 0 || j == COLS -1) {
            printf("*");
        }
        else {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I *think* it's meant to be a hollow square, not a solid one.

Comment: @PaulR: Ah! I just saw the edit. Working on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're making it overly complicated - try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("*****\n");
    printf("*   *\n");
    printf("*   *\n");
    printf("*   *\n");
    printf("*****\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_SIZE 32

int main(void){
    int i, n = 5;
    char line1[LINE_SIZE] = {0}, line2[LINE_SIZE] = {0};
    memset(line1, ' ', sizeof(line1)-1);
    memset(line1+sizeof(line1)-n-1, '*', n);
    memcpy(line2, line1, sizeof(line1));
    memset(line2+sizeof(line2)-n, ' ', n-2);

    puts(line1);
    for(i = n-2; i ; --i)
        puts(line2);
    puts(line1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void print_square(int size)
{
   int i;
   int j;

   for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       printf("*");
   }
   printf("\n");

   for(i = 1; i < size - 1; i++)
   {
       printf("*");
       for(j = 1; j < size - 1; j++)
       {
          printf(" ");
       }  
       printf("*");
       printf("\n");
   }

   for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       printf("*");
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int n;
for(n=1;n<4;n++){
    printf("*");
}
for (n=1;n<4;n++){
    printf("*   *\n");
}
for (n=1;n<=5;n++){
    printf("*");
}
for(n=5;n<4;n--){
    printf("*\n");
}
getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #define row 70
    #define coloumn 70
    #define buff_size row*coloumn
    int draw_Box(int x,int y,int height,int width,int pixel_width,char *);

    typedef struct
    {
        char r;
        char g;
        char b;
        char a;
    }rgba_t;

    typedef struct
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        int height;
        int width;
        int pixel_width;

        char * base_ptr;
    }box_t;

    rgba_t *rgba_ptr;
    unsigned char data[buff_size]={1};
    void main()
    {

        long unsigned int status,i,j=0;
        memset(data,' ',sizeof(data));
       if(status = draw_Box(28,28,15 ,15,3,data))
       {
         printf("out of boundary");
        return ;
       }

        for(i=0;i<buff_size;i++)
        {

            if(i%coloumn==0)
            {

                if(i==0)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%3d\n\n",(j++));
                }
            }
            printf("%2c ",data[i]);


        }
        printf("%3d\n\n",j);

            for(i=0;i<coloumn;i++)
        {



            printf("%2d ",i);


        }
        return ;


    }


    int draw_Box(int x,int y,int height,int width,int thick,char *base_ptr)
    {
        int x1,y1,i,j;
        x1 = x + height-1;
        y1 = y + width-1;
    //  char *box_base_ptr = (base_ptr+((x*10)+y));
        if((x1)>row || (y1) >coloumn)
        {

            return 1;
        }
    #if 1
    for(j=0;j<thick;j++)
    {   
        for(i=x+j;i<=x1-j;i++)
        {

              *(base_ptr+(i*coloumn)+y+j)=0x31+j;   
              *(base_ptr+(i*coloumn)+y1-j)=0x31+j;
        }
    }
    #endif  
    #if 1
    for(j=0;j<thick;j++)
    {
        for(i=y+1+j;i<y1-j;i++)
        {

              *(base_ptr+((x+j)*coloumn)+i)=0x31+j; 
              *(base_ptr+((x1-j)*coloumn)+i)=0x31+j;    
        }
    }
    #endif  
        return 0;
    //  for(i=x;)

    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanations as well.